# mySQL: подсчитать вхождения из другой таблицы для каждого ID

Tags: mysql, join

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT id FROM categories ORDER BY order_id ASC
```

Нужно получить общее кол-во вхождений для каждой категории из таблицы userdata, поля category_selection. 
Поле category_selection содержит список id категорий через запятую: 0,1,4,7

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `userdata` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `category_selection` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);
```

Чтобы проще было понять задачу, приведу примерный запрос, но нужно, чтобы был подсчет и строгое соответствие, т.к. Concat('%', c.id, '%') некорректно отрабатывает, на примере 0,4,6,86,7 и т.п.

```
 SELECT * 
FROM   categories c 
       LEFT JOIN userdata u 
              ON u.category_selection LIKE Concat('%', c.id, '%') 
ORDER  BY order_id ASC
```

Comment: а если категорий в userdata будет больше 80? Данные будут обрезаться. Может лучше сделать там по одной записи на категорию, тогда и количество будет легко считаться. Если структуру менять нельзя, то как считать количество, если у одного пользователя будут, например, категории 0, 1, 2, 1 (т.е. категория 1 встретилась два раза). Кстати, это еще одна причина того, что по одной записи на категорию будет проще

Comment: Структуру не хотелось бы переделывать, т.к. нужно будет все переписывать. Данные уникальны и проверяются на стороне сервера.  В принципе, можно как-то ограничить подсчет не более одного на user_id, при условии, если данные id категорий повторятся, но как построить логику запроса я не знаю... Дополнил основной пост примером, но как организовать подсчет вхождений, а не склейку не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Со строгим соответствием решение стандартное - добавляем разделители к категории и списку. С дублями, в принципе, тоже несложно - distinct по полю.

```
SELECT u.user_id, count(distinct c.id) as CategoriestCount
FROM   userdata u 
       LEFT JOIN categories c 
              ON concat(',',u.category_selection,',') LIKE Concat('%,', c.id, ',%') 
group by u.user_id
```

Но производительность и надёжность... гм... мягко говоря не очень.
Нормальные формы - они всё-таки не на пустом месте возникли.

Answer (score 0):

Или вложенным подзапросом:

```
select u.user_id, (
   select count(distinct c.id) 
   from categories c 
   where u.category_selection LIKE Concat('%', c.id, '%')) 
 from userdata u
```

Но присоединюсь к ответившим - отношение многие-ко-многим сделать и не мучить.
LIKE "%...%" в случае с как минимум mysql приводит к **полному** сканированию всей таблицы, невзирая на индексы (которых еще и нет)

Comment: Там в задаче по моему все таки имелось ввиду посчитать кол-во записей юзердата с данной категорией. просто принятый ответ почему то наоборот. Иначе я бы предложил посчитать кол-во запятых в поле и никуда больше не лазить :)